# What we do? vs. What do we do?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, difference

I'm a little confused about these sentences(?)/phrases(?). I would use "What do we do?" as a proper form in most cases, but I've recently noticed that many websites use "what we do" in their navigation bars or sections about their teams, e.g.

https://www.wagggs.org/en/what-we-do/
(look at the navigation bar)

https://www.lockheedmartin.com/us/what-we-do.html
(the navigation bar as well)

What's the difference between these two phrases? Which one should be put on the website, and why?

Comment: One is an interogative sentence, the other is a noun clause.

Comment: So, the first example "What we do" should be used without a question mark, and only for informative purposes. Am I right?

Comment: Correct. **this is what we do** means **this is what our sphere of activity is** or **this is what we specialize in**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing two different things here. **What do we do?** is an interrogative sentence asking what course of action one should proceed with. The first *do* is one of those so-called [**auxiliary verbs**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/auxiliary-verbs) in English that are used to form questions. The second *do* is nothing more than the main verb of the sentence. For example:

> I've cleaned the room up, done the dishes and the laundry. **What do I do now?** Oh, I know what I'm going to **do**! I'm going to clean the toilet. I completely forgot about the toilet!

**what we do**, on the other hand, is a non-question statement—a noun clause, as Cardinal aptly pointed out in the comments section. It can only be properly understood as part of a larger context. In your case, where two organizations are telling you information about themselves, it simply means the following: **this is what our sphere of activity is**, **this is what we specialize in** or **this is what our job is**. The verb *to do* is commonly used to ask people questions about their jobs:

> — What do you **do** for a living?
>   — I'm a taxi driver.
>
> — What is your job?
>   — I **do** Photoshop designs.

You would say **what we do** on your website and then describe what exactly your job is to let visitors to your website know what you can offer them.